# How to know which device are broken?

Tags: usb, hardware, dmesg, lsusb

Other than plugging out one by one, I got spammed periodically something like this (every 5 minutes or so) on `dmesg -w` :

```
[766815.453149] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767077.289501] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767086.925521] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767125.821544] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767131.049562] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767155.309577] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767246.089644] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767270.581663] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767433.853761] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[767509.977803] usb usb4-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

my `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1058:25ee Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book 25EE
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bc2:ab38 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Hub (Mass Storage)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab45 Seagate RSS LLC Backup+ Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 17ef:1015 Lenovo TP USB 3.0 Ultra Dock
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 17e9:4340 DisplayLink ThinkPad USB 3.0 Ultra Dock
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 17ef:1014 Lenovo TP USB 3.0 Ultra Dock
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:ab44 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Hub
Bus 002 Device 117: ID 17ef:1015 Lenovo TP USB 3.0 Ultra Dock
Bus 002 Device 121: ID 0951:170f Kingston Technology HyperX SoloCast
Bus 002 Device 116: ID 17ef:1014 Lenovo TP USB 3.0 Ultra Dock
Bus 002 Device 120: ID 256c:006d  Huion Tablet_GT1562
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1058:25ee Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book 25EE
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:25ee Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Book 25EE
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8290 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 078: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 077: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 001 Device 076: ID 258a:002a SINO WEALTH Gaming KB
Bus 001 Device 074: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 073: ID 2109:2811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 072: ID 2109:2811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 26ce:01a2 ASRock LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There are no 0004 port 0004

**UPDATE** `lsusb --tree`:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 40, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 41, If 5, Class=Communications, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 41, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 41, If 1, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 41, If 6, Class=CDC Data, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 41, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 41, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 41, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 43, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 42, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 5, Class=Communications, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 6, Class=CDC Data, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 125, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 125, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbfs, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 125, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 121, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 121, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 121, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 117, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 126, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 126, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 126, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 126, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 72, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 73, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 79, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 82, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 83, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 83, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 4, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 5, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

how to know which port is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The message is about USB hub port 4 on USB bus 4. Since the port fails to enable, any device plugged into it *would not* be visible in `lsusb`.

So, you should inventory your USB devices and see if you have a device that is *not listed* in `lsusb` output. That would be a good place to start testing.

Since the error message mentions USB bus 4, and the bus has no hubs other than the root hub (`Bus 004 Device 001`), the port that is reporting the problem would seem to be on the actual computer, and not on some external USB hub. Of course, if you have something like a Thunderbolt-connected dock, it might provide additional USB buses that would count as part of the "actual computer" as far as the USB subsystem is concerned.

Anyway, find the part that has at least two of your WD My Book 25EE portable drives connected to it, and start checking any other devices connected via USB to that part.

Since you have rather a lot of USB devices, `lsusb --tree` might be more useful to you than a plain `lsusb`, since the tree-formatted listing includes the hub port numbers.

But since the error is reported by the hub port, I would not expect any device to be visible at `Bus 04`, `Port 4` because a problem is being detected at the port level: it could be e.g. a short circuit in the USB cable, that would prevent any communication with the device at the other end of that cable. You would have to identify the port by looking at what other devices are in the same "branch" of the tree structure.

Comment: hmm, those two WD Mybook connected directly to back port of my PC

Comment: Then it looks like the failing device could be something else that's connected *directly* to your PC.